# swift reverse order of tableview cells

Tags: swift, tableview

my tableview is loaded from a dictionary, I'm trying to reverse the order the tableview is shown from,the dictionary is set like this

```
loadComments["set\(num)"] = ["\(usernameC)","\(timestamp)","\(commenttxt.text)"]
```

of course there would be many sets

and the tableview would be loaded like this

in the cellforRow function

```
   if let setInfo = loadComments["set\(indexPath.row)"] {// set data in cell }
```

this works fine but i want the results reversed so the last comment that was entered to be at the top of the tableview and not load in the bottom??

any ideas are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve this you will need to sort your data source (your dictionary in this case). Dictionaries by default are not ordered data structures, so you will need to create an ordered one from it (such as an array for example). For example, if you wanted to sort by the dictionaries key, then you could do something like this in Swift:

```
let dataSource = ["aaaaaa" : "Some data here", "bbbbbb" : "Some data here", "cccccc" : "Some data here"]
let sortedData = dataSource.sort{ $0.0 < $1.0 }
```

This will give you an array of tuples, which may not be the most use to you. If you wanted to order by key and then just store the data associated with it, you could append the map function like so:

```
let dataSource = ["aaaaaa" : "Some data here", "bbbbbb" : "Some data here", "cccccc" : "Some data here"]
let sortedData = dataSource.sort{ $0.0 < $1.0 }.map { $0.1 }
```

After sorting, remember you refresh your table view. You can do this by either refreshing the cells, the sections or the entire thing. Easiest way is like this:

```
tableView.reloadData()
```

Hope this helps you out :)